# Como plotar vários gráficos em uma folha A4 com margens definidas?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Para ilustrar a questão considerei a situação hipotética abaixo, utilizando as bibliotecas `ggplot2` e `gridExtra`.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(gridExtra)

 df<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)
 a<-ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y=y^2)) + xlab("Posição") + ylab("Função") + ggtitle("Posição x Função")+geom_point()
 b<-ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y=y^3)) + xlab("Posição") + ylab("Função") + ggtitle("Posição x Função")+ geom_point()
 c<-ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y=y^4)) + xlab("Posição") + ylab("Função") + ggtitle("Posição x Função") + geom_point()
 d<-ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y=y^5)) + xlab("Posição") + ylab("Função") + ggtitle("Posição x Função") + geom_point()
 e<-ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y=y^6)) + xlab("Posição") + ylab("Função") + ggtitle("Posição x Função") + geom_point()
 f<-ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y=y^7)) + xlab("Posição") + ylab("Função") + ggtitle("Posição x Função") + geom_point()
 grid.arrange(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

Como posso plotar os gráficos gerados por esta rotina em uma folha A4 levando em conta que:

- A orientação da folha seja Retrato e, as suas mas margens esquerda, superior, direita e inferior tenham respectivamente 3,3,2 e 2 centímetros;
- Os gráficos estejam dispostos lado a lado em duas colunas com 0,5cm de distância entre elas, um grid de 3x2;
- O tamanho das fontes do título seja 12 e das legendas 10.

Comment: Jean, dois detalhes: 1. Tem um parêntesis sobrando/faltando na sua primeira linha. 2. Sempre coloque o código de carregar os pacotes quando fizer uma pergunta ou der uma resposta, pelo código não é possível saber quais pacotes são necessários.

Comment: Você se importa apenas com a margem, ou também com o espaço que os gráficos vão ocupar? E o alinhamento na página?

Comment: @Molx - Obrigados pelas correções. Não havia pensado em detalhes além das margens... mas vou melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: @Jean, desculpe a pergunta, mas qual o objetivo disso? Talvez usar o `sweave` seja uma abordagem mais adequada, dependendo do seu objetivo.

Comment: @Bernado, tentei criar um problema parecido ao que me deparei, criei vários gráficos e preciso imprimi-los de uma forma organizada. Vou verificar o `sweave`. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso foi um pouco mais difícil do que o planejado, porque não consegui fazer o `pdf` funcionar com o `par(mai)`, para definir as margens. Para funcionar, fiz uma estratégia bem não-elegante, mas parece ter funcionado.

O que fiz foi zerar todas as margens dos gráficos e criar o pdf com área de plotagem de tamanho igual à uma folha A4. Então preenchi os espaços de margens/entre gráficos com grobs vazios.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

df<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)
a<-ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y=y^2)) + xlab("Posição") + ylab("Função") +
  ggtitle("Posição x Função") + geom_point() + theme(plot.margin=unit(rep(0, 4), "in"))
b<-ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y=y^3)) + xlab("Posição") + ylab("Função") +
  ggtitle("Posição x Função") + geom_point() + theme(plot.margin=unit(rep(0, 4), "in"))
c<-ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y=y^4)) + xlab("Posição") + ylab("Função") +
  ggtitle("Posição x Função") + geom_point() + theme(plot.margin=unit(rep(0, 4), "in"))
d<-ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y=y^5)) + xlab("Posição") + ylab("Função") +
  ggtitle("Posição x Função") + geom_point() + theme(plot.margin=unit(rep(0, 4), "in"))
e<-ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y=y^6)) + xlab("Posição") + ylab("Função") +
  ggtitle("Posição x Função") + geom_point() + theme(plot.margin=unit(rep(0, 4), "in"))
f<-ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y=y^7)) + xlab("Posição") + ylab("Função") +
  ggtitle("Posição x Função") + geom_point() + theme(plot.margin=unit(rep(0, 4), "in"))

pdf("gg.pdf", width=21/2.54, height=29.7/2.54) #Tamanho da A4, de cm para in
blank <- rectGrob(gp=gpar(col="white"))
grid.arrange(blank, blank, blank, blank, blank,
             blank, a, blank, b, blank,
             blank, blank, blank, blank, blank,
             blank, c, blank, d, blank,
             blank, blank, blank, blank, blank,
             blank, e, blank, f, blank,
             ncol = 5,
             widths = c(3, 7.75, 0.5, 7.75, 2), #Calculado a partir da largura da A4 e das margens
             heights = c(3, 7.9, 0.5, 7.9, 0.5, 7.9,2)) #Calculado a partir da altura da A4 e das margens
dev.off()
```

A resposta ainda é parcial, porque não tentei resolver a parte da fonte. Não sei se é possível usar essa definição de tamanho 12 ou 10, talvez seja melhor fazer os testes no `ggplot` e então definir manualmente.

Comment: qual a largura de blank?

Comment: @Jean A largura é definida em `widths`. São as larguras das margens e do espaçamento entre as figuras.

Comment: tudo funcionou perfeitamente! Caso você tenha mais alguma dica sobre o assunto ficarei agradecido.